# Why does the default Tomcat install on RedHat splinter the directories all over the file system?

Tags: tomcat, redhat

Working with our RHEL 6.6 deployments, the default Tomcat install looks like this:

```html
cd /usr/share/tomcat/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root        89 Apr 27 15:40 bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      11 Aug 13  2014 conf -> /etc/tomcat
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat     786 May 15 14:35 derby.log
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      22 Aug 13  2014 lib -> /usr/share/java/tomcat
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      15 Aug 13  2014 logs -> /var/log/tomcat
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat 9511425 Nov 10  2014 Application1.log
drwxr-xr-x. 7 tomcat tomcat      90 Apr 27 15:49 app-data
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      22 Aug 13  2014 temp -> /var/cache/tomcat/temp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      23 Aug 13  2014 webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat/webapps
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   tomcat      22 Aug 13  2014 work -> /var/cache/tomcat/work
```

This is a real hassle to work with; why would this massive linking-out be a good idea?  I do not get the reason for doing this.

I can see why you'd want to link-out the logs and maybe temp, but the others?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does the same thing too, and the reason is so that Tomcat's program code (/bin, /lib,  and temps files generated in work and temp, etc.) remain decoupled from the content code (webapps) so that you can upgrade Tomcat via Redhat's package management system without fear of losing your webapps or having to reconfigure Tomcat every time there is an update released. All of these links point to somewhere useful for Tomcat /wrt Redhat's install, but you don't have to use it.

Note that if you don't want to use Redhat's default install of Tomcat, uninstall it, and you can just roll out your own manual install. (scp a copy of Tomcat manually to /usr/ or whatever). Create a tomcat7 user account, create the missing sub folders for your web apps and permission them for Tomcat, and then setup an entry to start Tomcat on boot (e.g. create a startup script in /etc/init.d/tomcat) using tomcat7 as the user account to run as. And then there's the firewall and manual Tomcat config to follow, and you are now responsible for updates to it because it is a manual install. Note that if you are using SSL, Tomcat has the heartbleed vulnerability prior to 7.0.52, so make sure you are at least using that version or later.

Comment: Thanks but if you think about, I could just link webapps out to somewhere like /var/lib/tomcat/webapps and get the same results?  I'd also think it would be safer to upgrade with a side-by-side install and link to the same webapps in both instances; "deploy" and "rollback" then is just starting/stopping the instance so only one is running at time.  I can even see linking out the logs to a large log partition so they can be centrally managed but moving the lib and conf directories increases the complexity to manage with no clear benefit

Comment: I'll have to check if the same applies to Tomcat as it does to Apache; RedHat backports security patches to their officially supported versions.  for example, RHEL 7 updates to include openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7 which includes the HeartBleed fix backported from openssl-1.0.1g.  Same backporting goes for Apache 2.4; Tomcat was updated from 7.0.42 to 7.0.54 even though RH originally backported the HB fix into their 7.0.42 version.